# PKB Knowledge Articles in Customer Portal

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, customer-portal, knowledge, articles

I am using the PKB app ([app exchange link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU)) to get a simple knowledge base up and running in the context of both an authenticated (via customer portal) and unauthenticated site, but the site looks different in both cases despite having the same underlying code.

When viewing an article while unauthenticated, the site takes on the PKB look & feel as expected.

When viewing an article while authenticated, instead of taking on the PKB look & feel, the user is just sent to the standard article detail page.

In both cases, the URL is exactly the same.  It is of the form:

```
http://<site url>/articles/<article type>/<article url name>/?l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1
```

The only difference between the two scenarios is that in the first case the user is unauthenticated and has the access of the site "Public Access Settings", while in the second case the user is authenticated as a customer portal user.

Since the only difference between the two cases is access, this leads me to believe it is some sort of permission configuration issue.  However, i've verified the customer portal user has knowledge access, and if they didn't I wouldn't expect the standard article detail page to work either anyways.

I have thought of rewriting the article detail page myself, but it seems like a lot of work.  Is there a visualforce component that makes this a more reasonable task?  It's not clear to me how PKB is rendering the article content.

Ultimately, it's perplexing to me that the same exact url results in a completely different page.  Has anyone encountered this before?  Is this some type of salesforce limitation or have I set something up incorrectly?

Images of same site rendering differently below.

**Unauthenticated**

[image: Unauthenticated Site]

**Authenticated**

[image: Authenticated Site]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say "Customer Portal" do you mean Salesforce Customer Communities or the older Portal product?